# Jquery Veritical Slide Menu

Tags: jquery

I'm making a veritcal navigation menu that has sublevels. When the use clicks the top level link the sublevel menu is shown by giving it the class 'active'. If a sublevel menu is being shown and another top level link is clicked I want to remove the 'active' class from the sublevel menu which is currently being shown. I have tried calling remveClass from all the sublevel menus but i doesn't work. Please can I get some guidence on how to achive this.

```
<nav class="side-nav-wrap">
        <ul class="list-unstyled nav-icons-wrap">
            <li>
                <a href="" class="navbar-trigger" data-target="#homeLinks">
                    <i class="fa fa-home nav-icon"></i>
                    <span class="nav-icon-label">Home</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled subnav-drawer" id="homeLinks">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            Test1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-trigger', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.attr('data-target')){
                var $target = $this.attr('data-target')

                $($target).toggleClass('active');

                e.preventDefault();

            } 
        });
```

css

```
.subnav-drawer {
position: absolute;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 145px;
top:0px;
bottom: 0px;
left:85px;
display: none;}

.active{
display: block;}
```

Comment: Where?  I don't see where you tried to remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use next code on the adequate place for remove the active class on the element or elements that currently have it:

```
$(".active").removeClass("active");
```